# Try/Catch with if conditions in Java/Android

Tags: java, android, try-catch

I am trying to catch the exception and not allow the app to force close. Hence I am put the try and catch like the blow:

```
try 
{
  String[] words = message.split(" ");
  strBuilder.setLength(0);

  numberString = words[8];
  if (numberString.length() > 4) 
  {
    numberString = numberString.substring((numberString.length() - 4));
  } 

   if ((message.contains("return"))) 
   {
     amountString = words[0];
     amountString = amountString.replace(",", "");
     amountString = getFilter(message);
    }

   else 
    {
      for (int i = 12; i < words.length; i++) 
        {
         text = words[i];
         strBuilder.append(text + " ");
         str = strBuilder.toString();
        }

      amountString = words[1];
      amountString = amountString.replace(",", "");

      nameString = str;
    }

    Log.e("Value","= " + amountString + nameString + numberString);
} 
catch (NotFoundException e) 
{
   Log.e("ERROR","Value Not fetched");
}   

}
```

**I am trying the above code in a for loop...**

but the app still crashes and gives error in amountString = getFilter(message);
Why is this happening?

Do I need to insert try and catch before amount=getFilter(message);?

Comment: what Exception is `getFilter` throwing?  Maybe not a `NotFoundException`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only catching `NotFoundException` but there may be some other exception happening in your code execution that is crashing your app. So try catching `Exception` to find what is going wrong.

Comment: Yes, but better than catching `Exception`, review the actual stack trace.

Comment: @JohnBollinger can;t agree more ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Look at your catch statement:

```
catch (NotFoundException e) {
```

You're only catching one exception, a `NotFoundException`. I'd check Logcat and see what exception is thrown, and catch that instead.

If you want a quick and dirty solution, you can catch `Exception`. But that will catch anything at all. If you have a random `NullPointerException` or `NumberFormatException` it'll be caught too, which could mask serious issues or make debugging difficult.